# Erase using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

I am looking to erase an area in one shapefile by the area of another shapefile. After looking for as many resources as I can on this, I cannot get things to work.

```
def erase_shapes(self, to_erase, eraser, out_file):
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    feat1 = driver.Open(to_erase, 0)
    feat2 = driver.Open(eraser, 1)
    feat1Layer = feat1.GetLayer()
    feat2Layer = feat2.GetLayer()
    outDataSource = driver.CreateDataSource(out_file)

    out_ds = feat1Layer.Erase(feat1Layer, feat2Layer, outDataSource )
    out_ds = None
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR 6: Only one feature iterator can be active at a time

Using:

```
numberVar = feat1Layer.GetFeatureCount()
numberVar = feat2Layer.GetFeatureCount()
```

it is confirmed that there is only 1 feature in each dataset.

When I try to add an iterator:

```
for feat in feat2Layer:
    out_ds = feat1Layer.Erase(feat1Layer, feat, outDataSource)
    out_ds = None
```

I get:

> TypeError: in method 'Layer_Erase', argument 3 of type 'OGRLayerShadow *'

There is a lot of confusing information out there on how to get this to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: When posting code, don't just cut a method out of a class. Make it a complete and as runnable (as possible) example, including module imports and opening/setting of input data/variables etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Erase` method](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#Erase) signature is `Erase(Layer self, Layer method_layer, Layer result_layer, optional args...)`

You're doing two things incorrectly:

1. Passing the input layer in twice, first implicitly (basic python, `self` is always passed to object methods, you don't explicitly pass it), then explicitly as the 1st argument;
2. Passing a `Dataset` not a `Layer` as the `result_layer` argument.

Working example:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions()


def erase_shapes(to_erase, eraser, out_file):
    feat1 = ogr.Open(to_erase)
    feat2 = ogr.Open(eraser)
    feat1Layer = feat1.GetLayer()
    feat2Layer = feat2.GetLayer()

    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    outDataSource = driver.CreateDataSource(out_file)
    srs = feat1Layer.GetSpatialRef()
    outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer('', srs, ogr.wkbPolygon)

    out_ds = feat1Layer.Erase(feat2Layer, outLayer)
    out_ds = None

to_erase = "test1.shp"
eraser = "test2.shp"
out_file = "test3.shp"

erase_shapes(to_erase, eraser, out_file)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: beauty. Thank you very much. If my eraser has multiple features, will I have to do a for loop?

Comment: Yes the method_layer argument is a layer, not a feature so will use all features